# How do you uninstall Puppet from Mac OS X ?

Tags: macos, mac, puppet

I installed puppet 3.x on Mac OS 10.8.4 a few weeks back, and now want to remove it.
The installer.dmg does not come with an uninstaller, and there is no .app package to remove.

How do you uninstall puppet from Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Puppet does not have an uninstaller, you must manually remove the following files. (Tested on 3.2.3)

**Uninstalling**

Remove the following binaries

```
/usr/bin/puppet
/usr/sbin/puppet
```

Remove the following directories

```
/private/etc/puppet
/usr/share/doc/puppet
```

To get rid of the puppet user that appears on the login screen

```
sudo dscl . delete /Users/puppet
```

You will need to  reboot for the user to disappear

---

resources
[spuders blog - how to remove puppet from Mac](http://spuder.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/uninstalling-puppet-from-mac-os-x/)
[delete puppet installed via ruby](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/oUivogz8njE)
[remove hidden user from mac](http://ianwalter.roon.io/mac-command-to-delete-hidden-users)

Answer (score 10):

The [above answer](https://superuser.com/a/632329/225615) is incomplete, not all the files are removed with the above commands.

I was able to **completely uninstall** Puppet (on Mountain Lion) by running the following commands:

```
for f in $(pkgutil --only-files --files com.puppetlabs.puppet); do sudo rm /$f; done
for d in $(pkgutil --only-dirs --files com.puppetlabs.puppet | tail -r); do sudo rmdir /$d; done
sudo pkgutil --forget com.puppetlabs.puppet
```

Comment: Puppetlabs did a great job having the files actually delivered by the payload, this is a very smart and native way to go about removing it. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: With version 4.6.1 of the puppet agent you have to change com.puppetlabs.puppet to `com.puppetlabs.puppet-agent`. `for f in $(pkgutil --only-files --files com.puppetlabs.puppet-agent); do sudo rm /$f; done
for d in $(pkgutil --only-dirs --files com.puppetlabs.puppet-agent | tail -r); do sudo rmdir /$d; done
sudo pkgutil --forget com.puppetlabs.puppet-agent` After running this I still had files under /opt/puppetlabs so it doesn't seem to fully work currently.

Comment: The above solution worked for me when I had to uninstall Puppet 3 on El Capitan as well. (Haven't tried with Puppet 4.)